# BlackBerry - App connects to webservice on simulator, but not on device

Tags: networking, blackberry, tcp

i have developed an application, that gets installed in the mobile phone.
The brief information  of application is it is accessing web services, from another machine.
Now i tested the application on the simulator in 2 ways

> 1) MDS: in the application , there is a url of the machine, where web services are present. this url is in the stubs generated ,i make no changes to the url. and i start the  MDS-cs server , Now the application works fine.
>   2) Direct TCP: to the url , i append ;deviceside=true to the url. and now, this time, i dont start the MDS-CS, and the application works in this case.

But, now when i install these files in the device, the application doesnt work.
I havent tried it with MDS, becuase i need to take support from the blackberry team in our org. which would take more time.
So i have tried it with, Direct TCP, i wiped the device and installed the application. but it does not work.Please help me , in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Networking on a BlackBerry device can be a little complicated.  I highly recommend going through [this forum post](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242) for a primer on all of the issues and complexities involved with using HTTP on a BlackBerry.  Lots of very useful information in there.

Answer (score 0):

Another very good resource is this [developer video](http://www.blackberry.com/DevMediaLibrary/view.do?name=NetworkingTransportsII).