# How to get Httpconnection datastream on Blackberry device by using 3G

Tags: networking, blackberry

friends...

I have some questions about Blackberry 3G network...

Now, I developed Blackberry app and it works fine on simulator by using MDS...

Following is my code for HttpConnection..

httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ);

Problem is that it didn't work on device when I use 3G..

In case of Wifi, I solved this problem by adding  suffix, ";interface=wifi"...

But , I 'm worried that how I can solve this problem in case of 3G...

Anyone who has experienced this kind of problem?

If then, I hope to help me...

Best regards...

thanks again....

Comment: this has been asked a few times in the past:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939534/blackberry-app-connects-to-webservice-on-simulator-but-not-on-device  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382175/blackberry-wifi-http-connection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861036/blackberry-http-connection-issue

Comment: Dear friend, Michael..

Thanks for taking time  for me...

I read above links that you send to me, but it's not still worked on my device...

If possible, would you send sample project or sample code to me that works on device for 3g Network?

very very thanks ....

Answer (score 0):

please add the appropriate connection suffix while making the http connection.

String url = "http://abc.com//index.html";

url = url  + getConnectionString();

Please use the below url to get the **connection suffix** OR **getConnectionString**() for the URL string

http://www.localytics.com/blog/2009/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device/

Specifying the connection suffix "deviceside=true" requires the device have the **APN** correctly configured, or you include APN specification in the URL.

**APN setting is very important**, if you are making the http connection using the cellular network (without BB plan or WIFI)

Have a look at this [video](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742?name=NetworkingTransportsII). as well